# Spring Boots - org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException

Tags: spring-boot

This is my first Spring boot application and I am getting org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException.
I went through other StackOverflow questions and tried options mentioned. Added unique and nullable for Id.

This is not an auto generated id and my Entity looks like below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TBL_EMPLOYEES")
public class EmployeeEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name="emp_id", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private Long emp_id;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="email", nullable=false, length=200)
    private String email;

    public EmployeeEntity() {

    }

    public EmployeeEntity(Long emp_id, String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        this.emp_id = emp_id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return emp_id;
    }


    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "EmployeeEntity [id=" + emp_id + ", firstName=" + firstName + 
                ", lastName=" + lastName + ", email=" + email   + "]";
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **`@Generated`** for primary key column to generate them.

```
...

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="emp_id", unique=true, nullable=false)
private Long emp_id;

...
```

you can use any of these values like below...

- ***AUTO :*** Hibernate selects the generation strategy based on the used
  dialect,
- ***IDENTITY :*** Hibernate relies on an auto-incremented database
  column to generate the primary key,
- ***SEQUENCE :*** Hibernate requests the
  primary key value from a database sequence,
- ***TABLE :*** Hibernate uses a
  database table to simulate a sequence.